# Using javascript to set the height of a div based on browser window size

Tags: javascript

I want the size of my div to dynamically change based on the size of the browser window. This is what I have so far.

```
var myHeight;

if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {

    //Non-IE 

    myHeight = window.innerHeight;

} else if (document.documentElement &&

    (document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {

    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode' 

    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

}

window.onload = function () {
    console.log(myHeight - 40);
    var primaryHeader = document.getElementById('primary-header'); //.setAttribute("height","myHeight");
    primaryHeader.style.height = myHeight;
}
```

I can get it to print out what the height of the browser is but I can't seem to apply that as the height of the div.

Any help would be amazing thanks.

Comment: "IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'" is incorrect. All versions of IE that I'm aware of support `innerWidth`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
primaryHeader.style.height = myHeight + 'px';
```

In css, `px` is added to the end of pixel values.  A value by itself is unknown to css and will be ignored.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cykt6/)

Answer (score 0):

Height is a kind of length. Lengths require units.

Try `myHeight+"px";`